# Show Malaysia cities based on states chosen

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

I want to do a Malaysia states and cities drop down list.

- Here is my initial page: (test3.php)

[image]

- When I select KL, my expectation output of the city shown as following:

[image]

- When I select Selangor, my expectation output of the city shown as following:

[image]

- State data json **($stateJsonObject)**

  ```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [stateId] => s1 [stateName] => Kuala Lumpur) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [stateId] => s2 [stateName] => Selangor))
  ```
- City data json **($cityJsonObject)**

  ```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c1 [cityName] => Kajang [cityStateId] 
  => s2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c2 [cityName] => Seputeh 
  [cityStateId] => s1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c3 [cityName] => Shah 
  Alam [cityStateId] => s2 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c4 [cityName] => 
  Klang [cityStateId] => s2 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c5 [cityName] => 
  Kepong [cityStateId] => s1 ))
  ```
- Code (test3.php)

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function showCity()
      {
          //state id from drop down list
          var stateId = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value;

          //CODE HERE
      }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <form action="test3.php" method="post">
      State:
      <select name="state" id="state" onchange="showCity();">
          <option value ="">select one</option>
          <?php
              for($i = 0; $i < count($stateJsonObject); $i++)
              {
                  echo '<option value = '.$stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateId.'>';
                  echo $stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateName;
                  echo '</option>';
              }
          ?>
      </select>

      <br />

      City:
      <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value ="">select one</option>
      </select>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Based on the above reference, below is my questions: 
  (1) How do I compare the **state id** between js and php (json) on *CODE HERE* section? 
  (2) How to display the city drop down list based on **state** that I choose on *CODE HERE* 
    section?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it you have two options:

1.) load whole object in one "big" JSON and have it ready in Javascript - then just manipulate select's with JS.

2.) if number one is not performing so well (biiiiig data) "lazy" load selects - again with AJAX - and render selects with JS.

So - use JS for all manipulation where possibe and I think it's easiest :)

p.s.: When writing methods for rendering selects - think well about all possible scenarios and also have a reset function for them - it will help you at the end :)