# Pass city name from php to js (part 2)

Tags: javascript, php, json

Cont. on [Show Malaysia cities based on states chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652620/show-malaysia-cities-based-on-states-choosen)

- City data json **($cityJsonObject**)

  ```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c1 [cityName] => Kajang [cityStateId] 
  => s2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c2 [cityName] => Seputeh 
  [cityStateId] => s1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c3 [cityName] => Shah 
  Alam [cityStateId] => s2 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c4 [cityName] => 
  Klang [cityStateId] => s2 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c5 [cityName] => 
  Kepong [cityStateId] => s1 ))
  ```
- code (cityName)

  ```
  <?php
      for($i = 0; $i < count($cityJsonObject); $i++)
      {
          echo $cityJsonObject[$i]->cityName;

          //PASS VARIABLE TO JS
      }
  ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      //GET VARIABLE FROM PHP AND DISPLAY CITY NAME
  </script>
  ```
- From above code, I can get the following:

  ```
  Kajang 
  Seputeh
  Shah Alam
  Klang
  Kepong
  ```
- My question is how to pass the above city name into a variable and pass to js? How should I do?

Comment: you can simply add your php codes into script tags. I mean, write your php codes into script tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` and output a string which will be parsed easily by javascript

Try this code

```
<?php
    $array_to_js = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($cityJsonObject); $i++)
    {
        $array_to_js[] = $cityJsonObject[$i]->cityName;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //GET VARIABLE FROM PHP AND DISPLAY CITY NAME
    var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($array_to_js, JSON_HEX_QUOT) ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

// your php code here maybe you can need json_encode(), I'm not sure I get what you mean.
echo json_encode($cityJsonObject);
echo '<script>';
?>
```