# Get state name from drop down list after click submit button (part 3)

Tags: php, html, json

Cont. on [Pass city name from php to js (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668815/pass-city-name-from-php-to-js-part-2)

State data json (**$stateJsonObject**):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [stateId] => s1 [stateName] => Kuala Lumpur) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [stateId] => s2 [stateName] => Selangor)
)
```

Code (stateName):

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<form action="test3.php" method="post">
    State:
    <select name="state" id="state" onchange="showCity(this, 'city')">
        <option value ="">select one</option>
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < count($stateJsonObject); $i++)
        {
            echo '<option value = '.$stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateId.'>';
            echo $stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateName;
            echo '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>        
</body>
</html>
```

My question is:

When I choose `Selangor` from drop down list, after I click submit button, how do I keep the `Selangor` name in the drop down list selected?

Comment: is this on the same page?

Comment: @Ghost I'm beginning to wonder why the OP's code (first related question) http://stackoverflow.com/q/26652620/ then a (part 2) http://stackoverflow.com/q/26668815/ then this one (being part 3); *baffled* and a big WT*?

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually i've answered a question much like this kind before, it was a big assignment project, i answered one of the parts of it. eventually all the parts were completed. (thats from out of nothing lol)

Comment: Hi, Ghost. Yes, on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is submitted on the same page, you could add the currently submitted entry and put a checked attribute inside the loop:

```
<form action="test3.php" method="post">
    State:
    <select name="state" id="state" onchange="showCity(this, 'city')">
        <option value ="">select one</option>
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < count($stateJsonObject); $i++)
            {
                $selected = ($stateJsonObject[$i]->stateId == $_POST['state']) ? 'checked' : '';
                echo "<option value='".$stateJsonObject[$i]->stateId."' $selected>";
                echo $stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateName;
                echo '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Or with a foreach variant:

```
foreach($stateJsonObject as $state) {
    $stateId = $state->stateId;
    $stateName = $state->stateName;
    $selected = ($stateId == $_POST['state']) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo "<option value='$stateId' $selected>$stateName</option>";
}
```

Comment: I corrected your code. Becoz $_POST['state'] = stateid, therefore need to match stateid, not state name.

Comment: Hi, Ghost. Can you please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710109/keep-value-in-city-drop-down-listlast-part answer my question?

Comment: @user3905044 actually its essentially the same, you can use the same method as this one

Comment: You meant that use PHP to get the name?

Comment: @user3905044 yes just get the name thru post, its submitted right?