# keep value in city drop down list(part 4)

Tags: javascript, php, json

Cont. from [Get state name from drop down list after click submit button (part 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686050/get-state-name-from-drop-down-list-after-click-submit-button-part-3)

- State data json (**$stateJsonObject**)

  ```
  Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [stateId] => s1 [stateName] => Kuala Lumpur) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [stateId] => s2 [stateName] => Selangor)
  )
  ```
- City data json (**$cityJsonObject**)

  ```
  Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object 
  ( [cityId] => c1 [cityName] => Kajang [cityStateId] => s2 ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object 
  ( [cityId] => c2 [cityName] => Seputeh [cityStateId] => s1 ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c3 [cityName] => Shah Alam [cityStateId] => 
  s2 ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c4 [cityName] => Klang [cityStateId] => s2  
  ) 
  [4] => stdClass Object ( [cityId] => c5 [cityName] => Kepong [cityStateId] => s1    
  )
  )
  ```
- Code (test3.php)

  ```
  <?php
      $cityState = array();
      $cityName = array();

      for($j = 0; $j < count($cityJsonObject); $j++)
      {
          $cityState[] = $cityJsonObject[$j] -> cityStateId;
          $cityName[] = $cityJsonObject[$j] -> cityName;
      }
  ?>

  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function showCity(state, target_id)
      {
          var stateId = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value; 

          var target = document.getElementById(target_id);
          target.length = 0;
          target.options[0] = new Option('select one', '');
          target.selectedIndex = 0;

          var cityState = <?php echo json_encode($cityState, JSON_HEX_QUOT) ?>;
          var cityName = <?php echo json_encode($cityName, JSON_HEX_QUOT)?>; 

          for(k = 0; k < cityState.length; k++)
          {
              if(stateId == cityState[k])
              {
                  target.options[target.length] =
                  new Option(cityName[k],cityName[k]);         
              }
          }  
      }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form action="test3.php" method="post">
      State:
      <select name="state" id="state" onchange="showCity(this, 'city')">
          <option value ="">select one</option>
          <?php
              $select_sign = '';
              for($i = 0; $i < count($stateJsonObject); $i++)
              {
                  if($stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateId == $_POST['state']) 
                  {$select_sign = "SELECTED";}else{$select_sign = "";}
                  echo '<option value = '.$stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateId.' 
                  '.$select_sign.'>';
                  echo $stateJsonObject[$i] -> stateName;
                  echo '</option>';
              }
          ?>
      </select>

      <br />

      City:
      <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value ="">select one</option>
      </select>

      <br />

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>        
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- My question is I choose **Selangor** from state drop down list, after that I choose **Klang** from city drop down list. After I click submit button, how should I keep **Klang** name in the city drop down list selected?

Answer (score 0):

You may use either of following options,

- Use AJAX to submit the form. Then the page will not be reloaded and
  you can keep the value unchanged.
- Use HTML5 local storage (or cookies) to keep track of the city name
  that should be selected. When page loads, check if the value for city
  is saved and if saved, set the select to the saved value.